# how to attach image on mail using phpmailer

Tags: php, email

i use phpmailer to send email to someone from my page but the problem is the image that is being attach is not showing on the email..

```
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('../responsive-email/images/faithbook.png', 'faithbook_logo');

<img src="cid:faithbook_logo" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
```

my test page is:

```
 test.com/test/
```

inside test folder is where my responsive-email folder.
i even tried to do this `$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('test.com/test/responsive-email/images/faithbook.png', 'faithbook_logo');` but still it doesn't work

but when i paste the url to the addressbar of my browser it show the image..

When i tried sending it to a yahoo account the image doesn't show up but when i tried it to a google account it shows.. is there any approach to show the image on yahoo mail also?.

Comment: This seems to be a path issue

Comment: im sending the mail to a yahoo account .. and it doesn't work.. now when i send it to a gmail account the image shows..